# How to reference a DBML file in anaspx file?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, ascx

I have a ascx file and dbml linq file. i need to write c# script inside the ascx file, for that i need to use .dbml file. I dnt know how to reference it in my ascx file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking inline code in your ASCX? If so, why oh why. Just put in the code-behind (where it belongs). Or better yet via a repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data.Linq.DataContext;
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't actually reference the DBML file directly, you reference the classes generated by the DBML file. You need to use a `<%@ Import %>` directive, or a `Imports` (VB) or `using` (C#) statement to reference the namespace of the DBML file.

I recommend reading ScottGu's blog about [LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx).

PS
It's impolite to "thank in advance" on this site. If someone gives you the correct answer, thank them by marking their answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: <%@ Import Namespace="Forum" %>  
 public void GetForum()
{
    DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();}                                           
This is how I do in the ascx file .. but no luck. still the same issue from this, Any idea?

Comment: @tvi. I think we will need to see some more code before we can get an idea of what you need. Edit your question, and include the code you have already written, then explain what you want to achieve and what is actually happening. Include any error messages you receive. Thanks.